# text-only bookmark bar in Chrome or Opera

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, opera

The only reason why I'm still using the old Opera 12 is that it allows **text-only** bookmarks and folders on the bookmarks-bar:

[image]

But there are already a bunch of websites out there, which are not supported anymore by Opera 12, so I need Chrome additionally. But for most of my work I still use the old Opera as it so much more convenient. The new Opera 19/20 is very similar and I'd like to change to Chrome or Opera 20 completely.

**Is there a way to customize the appearance of the favicons to text-only, like in the screenshot above, for these two browsers?** Any changes in the registry? themes? add-ins? an option I have overseen?

Comment: Why not use Firefox?

Comment: @harrymc For various reasons. Firefox would also require add-ins, which are going to be outdated from time to time and I have the same problem again. I'm looking for a simple hack like [this](http://robcee.net/2013/bookmarks-deiconizer-deprecation-and-fix/) (that's the one which was used on FF, but not working anymore)

Comment: An old FF add-on can be made to work on the latest version by [changing its compatibility](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility). I'm currently using several outdated add-ons with the latest FF. Mozilla also stopped enforcing this for recent-enough add-ons.

Comment: If it is a space saving exercise how about deleting the text and only have the favicon?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams: that is no option at all, too colorful. And "nice" favicons would be to hard to maintain.

Comment: @thewaywewalk either use Opera or FF as there is no setting in Chrome to remove them but you can edit with your own from like here http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3032/google_chrome_how_to_change_icons_on_the_bookmarks_bar/

Comment: Hey @RobertSeifert, I'm having the exact same problem and I see it's been 9 years. Did you find a solution? Thank you in advance. It's nice to find that the exact same problem has once been posed.

Comment: @Emilio I switched to firefox. Its no standard feature there neither, but you will find the solution (css sheet) on google or here on SU.

Comment: @RobertSeifert thank you for your reply. Personally, I decided to clear out the bookmarks bar altogether, and stay in Chrome. I don't like having icons there, and the extra space between adress bar and content is nice. Again, I appreciate you taking a moment to share the update.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extension for Chrome called [No favicons](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mnaaoncljflaeohddihlkbfooicoajej). It hides all the favicons so you don't see any favicon on your tabs either. But it does the job hiding bookmark favicons.

It's not perfect, but you should get you pretty close to what you want to do. Apparently, you will need to revisit each page in your bookmark bar. This will cause the favicon to try to reload. The extension will kick in, and insert a blank one instead. It might leave a little space behind, but it will get rid of the icon.

As far as I know, there's no other way to do this in Chrome. It's not a feature that's built in.

Comment: sry for the late reply. It is not really an option, as it doesn't save space on the bar.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest returning to Firefox, which you say have used before but abandoned because
[the add-on](http://robcee.net/2013/bookmarks-deiconizer-deprecation-and-fix/) that you used was depreciated.

First, I think that Firefox can be customized to do what you want without any add-on.

Second, even an outdated add-on can be rendered usable by [changing its compatibility](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility).
I'm currently using several outdated add-ons with the latest version of Firefox.
Mozilla has also stopped enforcing version compatibility for recent-enough add-ons.

Comment: That is the temporary solution I started to use now. "Roomy bookmarks toolbar" extension works very nicely. I hope you're right and there won't be any compatibility issues with every new version. I liked opera/chrome because of its performance, but that is another discussion. Opera 12 had all the possibilities of the mentioned FF extension by default, hopefully the new one will reach the same functionality again someday.

Comment: The newest FF is as fast as the others, but its main strength is and was always the add-ons.