# Only titles in bookmarks bar

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, favicon

I like my digital space like I like my material space: clean and tidy. And I'd rather have only titles in my bookmarks bar. No favicons. Zen style.

Sometimes, less is more.

Is it possible to remove favicons from the bookmarks bar and have titles only? I'm using Chrome 114.0.5735.199.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/702447/text-only-bookmark-bar-in-chrome-or-opera) from 9 years ago asks exactly the same. There are two answers: one of them suggests returning to Firefox, which is not my preference, and the other one suggests using an extension, which doesn't seem to exist anymore as the link displays a 404 error, and it wouldn't really solve the problem as it would left a blank space. Blank spaces count. Always.

There's also [this thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22670939/hide-favicon-in-bookmarks-bar?hl=en) with one simple answer: you can't. It's 4 years old.

Is there any solution to this, workable today?

Thank you.

Update:

A search for "personalize bookmark favicon" took me to an extension called [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh), and also to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1053584/is-there-a-way-to-customise-bookmark-icons-in-chrome) where said extension is mentioned in the accepted answer. Another answer also mentioned the extension [Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favicon-changer/ijaabbaphikljkkcbgpbaljfjpflpeoo/related). It also mentions [this Chrome feature-request](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/13499485?hl=en), but it's about folder icons.

Bookmark Favicon Changer did change the icons to a png file I gave it, through the extension's options page, and reverted to the original icon when I visited the website. The other extension did nothing at all.

I tried the first extension again through the Extensions Button next to the URL bar, and it changed the bookmark's favicon without reverting when visiting the website. Additionally, it changed the icon in the tabs bar. I'm not sure I agree with that, and in any case I'd rather be able to remove the icon altogether. The option "Remove icon" from this extension just leaves a traditional internet icon in its place.

Comment: Nothing in the bookmarks API (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/) suggests that's possible and an extension would be the only way to do it.

Comment: @Destroy666 Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing out the API. I'm not familiar with it. The extensions I've tried either failed or got partial results. I just updated the question with the details.

Comment: To be honest, @Destroy666, I think your comment acccurately answers my question negatively, or more precisely, it describes the only workaround. If you want to post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that, but I'll write a more detailed answer if I'll find time to check it more accurately. There could be some workaround, e.g. the extensions you tried were just messing with favicons from what I see. Maybe thre's a better way to mess with them only for bookmarks, doubtful, but their source code could be checked.